# How to Convert Kindle Ebook to PDF Using ONLY a PC

Tags: pdf, ebook, kindle

I have a Kindle eBook, but I do not want to use Amazon's Kindle Reader online to read it. I would rather convert my Kindle eBook to a PDF file and then view it on Firefox's PDF viewer if possible.

I've heard that a possible solution is to go to **"My Account >> Manage Your Content and Devices"** and then downloading the `.azw` files from Amazon's website, but this method requires a Kindle device which I don't have.

Is there any way I can download my eBook as `.pdf` using ***Only*** a PC?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can download my eBook as .pdf using Only a PC?

Kindle support AZW, AZW3, AZW4, TPZ, PRC, Mobi, PRC, KFX file formats. As you are already aware you can download you ebook with as AZW files. However, these files are DRM protected. If you want to convert them to pdf, you need to remove the DRM (which is not the scope of this question and probably not recommended on this site), then use Calibre to convert them on your PC.

Comment: Wait, how can I import ebooks into Calibre if I do NOT have a Kindle device? Without a Kindle device, I get the following error: **"You have selected content that is not compatible with any of your registered devices. Please remove incompatible content from selection for eligible devices to appear"**

Comment: @Odie Download your ebooks to your PC. Calibre can convert them on your PC provided of course the drm is removed

Comment: How can I download them to my PC? I have no Kindle.